# Table border color with hover

Tags: css

How to make td border color work properly with `:hover`?

When you hover the last row the bottom border color is not changing as expected

```css
.list{
    table-layout:fixed;
    border-spacing:0;
}

.list-tr:hover > td{
    border-color:red;
}

.list-tr:hover + tr > td{
    border-top-color:red;
}

.list-td{
    border-top:1px solid blue;
}

.list-tr:last-child .list-td{
    border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="list">
<tbody>
<tr class="list-tr">
<td class="list-td">row1</td>
<td class="list-td">row1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="list-tr">
<td class="list-td">row2</td>
<td class="list-td">row2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="list-tr">
<td class="list-td">row3</td>
<td class="list-td">row3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for the red border coloring on `:hover`. If you look at the style tab in the dom, you can see the `.list-tr:hover > td` selector **is in fact** applied to the last bar on `:hover` but that the `.list-tr:last-child .list-td` selector has a greater specificity.

[image]

Increasing the specificity of `.list-tr:hover > td` to `.list-tr:hover > td.list-td` and it works as expected. You could also lower the specificity of the `:last-child` selector.

```css
.list {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.list-tr:hover > td.list-td { /* increase specificity */
  border-color: red;
}

.list-tr:hover + tr > td {
  border-top-color: red;
}

.list-td {
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
}

.list-tr:last-child .list-td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="list">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="list-tr">
      <td class="list-td">row1</td>
      <td class="list-td">row1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list-tr">
      <td class="list-td">row2</td>
      <td class="list-td">row2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list-tr">
      <td class="list-td">row3</td>
      <td class="list-td">row3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

### Pointer

When applying colors conditionally like this it's easier to first apply the main styles regardless of color (i.e. `border`), then add the colors in the successive selectors. For example...

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid black; /* set base color */
}

.red {
  border-color: red;
}

.green {
  border-color: green;
}
```

> This doesn't *really* apply to you example but good rule of thumb. This also applies to other color variant-styles or styles with multiple values in general.

Answer (score -1):

Add another rule for the last border

```css
.list{
    table-layout:fixed;
    border-spacing:0;
}

.list-tr:hover > td{
    border-color:red;
}

.list-tr:hover + tr > td{
    border-top-color:red;
}

.list-td{
    border-top:1px solid blue;
}

.list-tr:last-child .list-td{
    border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}
.list-tr:last-child:hover .list-td{
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table class="list">
<tbody>
<tr class="list-tr">
<td class="list-td">row1</td>
<td class="list-td">row1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="list-tr">
<td class="list-td">row2</td>
<td class="list-td">row2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="list-tr">
<td class="list-td">row3</td>
<td class="list-td">row3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```